# save sonata media path into twig variable

Tags: symfony, twig, sonata-admin, sonata-media-bundle

I want to store full path of image (sonata media bundle) into variable in twig. Is that possible?

If I write:

```
{% set pic = path item.image, 'big' %}
```

it throws me an error: Unexpected token "name" of value "item" ("end of statement block" expected) ...

If I write:

```
{% set pic = item.image %}
```

then it works, but it stores only name of the file, not full path.

Comment: Check this question, there are two extensions doing the job: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16637616/sonata-media-bundle-acces-media-url/28380265

Answer (score 6):

Why don't you do like this ?

```
{% set rendered %}{% path item.image, 'big' %}{% endset %}
....
Here is my path {{ rendered }}
```

Comment: Best answer, people forgot you can set var like this.

Answer (score 1):

There is not such a function available (there is a `path()` function to generate routes). You have to create your own twig extension with this custom function. Read all about that [in the documentation](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/templating/twig_extension.html).

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you can solve with:

`<img src="{% path media, 'small' %}" data-href="{% path media, 'big' %}">`