# Slightly different syntax for Twig media reference yields different results -- why?

Tags: php, symfony, twig, sonata-media-bundle

I am working on a project that uses Twig and the Sonata Media Bundle.

In one part of my template, I have the following line:

```
<img src="{% path media, 'reference' %}" >
```

... and in that same Twig template, I have (inside of a logic block) this line of assignment:

```
image: {src: path(media, 'reference'), alt:''}
```

... and while the fist line works, the second yields an error stating:

> None of the chained routers were able to generate route: Route
>   'Story2_Ernährung_damals (1).jpg' not found

**What am I doing wrong here?**

Comment: Are u feeding the same data to both snippets?

Comment: Yes. The same data is going to both snippets.

Comment: Try this `image: {'src': (path(media, 'reference')), alt:''}`

Comment: Good guess. It gave me the same error.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like I may have to write a Twig extension just to access the image url. Eeep!

[Sonata Media Bundle : acces media url](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16637616/sonata-media-bundle-acces-media-url)